# Format whole document in Visual studio. P and H1 tags are getting split over more that one row

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, formatting

When I press format whole document in Visual studio, some tages like "h1" and  "p" got split over more then one row

```
<h1>
    <%# something %></h1>
```

What I want to happen is that everything stays at one row.

```
<h1><%# something %></h1>
```

I checked out the formatting settings under Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Format > Tag Specific Options for h1 and p its set to "before and after", also the default settings are set this option.

Anyone can tell me how to prevent this the extra line breaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking into VS, I would try adding a new tag under Client Html Tags.
Add the new tag "%" and set the formatting, no closing tags and no line-breaks.

I think this should work for you in format

```
<h1><% something %></h1>
```